# How to unlist an org-mode plain list?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how do I unlist an `org-mode` plain list?

I have a plain list that looks like:

```
* header

  - List item 1.
  - List item 2.
  - List item 3.
```

I want to remove the plain list formatting and convert it to plain
text:

```
* header

List item 1.  List item 2.  List item 3.
```

I want to do this programmatically.  Are there `org` facilitates
to strip off the bullets and refill the text, or do I
need to roll my own?

Comment: Have you tried a keyboard macro? (There may be an existing org-mode command that does what you want, though - dunno.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select the region with the items and remove the bullets with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-toggle-item` afterwards type <kbd>M-q</kbd> to run `org-fill-paragraph`.

If you need that more often you could bind `org-toggle-item` to a key of your choice in your init file.

Example:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c i") #'org-toggle-item)
```

One programmatic solution would be:

```el
(defun myorg-list-to-text ()
  "Transform item list at point into section text.
Searches for the next item list if there is none at point."
  (save-mark-and-excursion
    (unless (org-in-item-p)
      (org-list-search-forward (org-item-beginning-re)))
    (set-mark (org-end-of-item-list))
    (org-beginning-of-item-list)
    (when (org-at-item-checkbox-p)
      (org-toggle-checkbox '(4)))
    (org-toggle-item nil)
    (org-fill-paragraph)
    ))
```

---

Test conditions:

- emacs-version: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29
- Emacs started with `emacs -Q` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize`
- org-version: Org mode version 9.1.13 (9.1.13-elpaplus @ /mnt/c/Users/Tobias.Zawada/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20180618/)
- Test file `test.org` with data:

```org
 ** test

 - [X] first
 - [-] second
 - [X] third
 - fourth
```

- Place point at end of heading and call `myorg-list-to-text`
- Undo, place point at end of `first` and call `myorg-list-to-text`
- Undo, place point at end of `fourth` and call `myorg-list-to-text`

All tests deliver:

```el
** test

first second third fourth
```